# How to calculate FPDF column heights to minimize vertical space

Tags: php, multiple-columns, fpdf

I've searched and cannot find anything at all related to my problem. I assume this would be a common problem for coders working in layout formats (like PDF).

Here's my problem. I am producing PDF files in FPDF using PHP 7.x and need to maximize the use of vertical space on the resulting page by making multiple columns approximately the same length. Given a single array of arrays of varying length, I need to produce an array containing X columns of elements properly reordered so that I can use the resulting array to add the columns to the PDF. The trick is to order them in such a way that all columns end up being as close to the same length as possible.

Here is my array:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'Section A Title' => 
        [
            'Footing',
            'Framing',
            'Electrical Rough',
            'Electrical Finish',
            'Plumbing Rough',
            'Final Inspection'
        ],
    'Section B Title' =>
        [
            'Floor/Interior',
            'Concrete flatwork preparation'
        ],
    'Section C Title' =>
        [
            'Building',
            'Zoning',
            'Road Access'
        ],
    'Section D Title' =>
        [
            'Private utility lines identified and marked',
            'Site Preparation (pre-construction)',
            'Purchase of (pre-construction) fill material',
            'Obstruction removal',
            'Termite pre-treatment',
            'Final/Finish grading',
            'Dumpster/Trash removal',
            'Utility line marking/digging clearance'
        ],
    'Section E Title' =>
        [
            'Temporary electrical service',
            'Permanent electrical rough-in/hookup',
            'Gas service rough-in/hookup'
        ]
];
```

If two columns are desired, then the resulting array would look like the following (note that column 0 results in 14 lines and column 1 has 13 lines):

```
<?php

$result = [
    '0' => //Column 1
        ['Section A Title' => 
            [
                'Footing',
                'Framing',
                'Electrical Rough',
                'Electrical Finish',
                'Plumbing Rough',
                'Final Inspection'
            ],
        ['Section B Title' =>
            [
                'Floor/Interior',
                'Concrete flatwork preparation'
            ],
        ['Section C Title' =>
            [
                'Building',
                'Zoning',
                'Road Access'
            ]
        ],
    '1' => //Column 2
        ['Section D Title' =>
            [
                'Private utility lines identified and marked',
                'Site Preparation (pre-construction)',
                'Purchase of (pre-construction) fill material',
                'Obstruction removal',
                'Termite pre-treatment',
                'Final/Finish grading',
                'Dumpster/Trash removal',
                'Utility line marking/digging clearance'
            ],
        ['Section E Title' =>
            [
                'Temporary electrical service',
                'Permanent electrical rough-in/hookup',
                'Gas service rough-in/hookup'
            ]
        ]
];
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that is not working as you want it to. Hint, you'll need to go through your arrays of data with PHP and calculate how to group things before you start creating the PDF.

Comment: That's my main problem. I don't know where to start in grouping the arrays by length to know which "column" to add them to.